# Idle/Walk/Run Animation in unreal engine 4.27

Tags: unreal-engine4

As you can see in the video, my running animation looks weird. My character runs forward alright, but the animation looks off (like it's constantly resetting).

I have tried everything (from using different run animations, to disabling root motion like some people have suggested), but nothing seems to work. Please help me solve this issue.
[Here's the video](https://youtu.be/pLBFu4pk2WE)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using animations from mixamo you should select "In Place" option before downloading it.

[image]